# Можно ли менять включать/выключать директивы компиляции в скомпилированных DCU файлах?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

Вот есть например в одном каталоге dcu файл сформированый из pas (там же), в котором часть процедур и функций компилируется (входит\не входит) в зависимости от разных DEFINE в файле my.inc (там же).

Вопрос: если я pas файл убираю, и в проекте этот dcu указываю, то будет ли влиять на компиляцию изменения в inc?

Т.е. если нет исходника, будет ли при перекомпиляции проекта учитываться изменения в коде (вкл\выкл функции) в зависимости от настроек в inc файле?

Comment: вы знаете что `dcu` это аббревиатура "_delphi compiled unit_"?  Он уже скомпилирован, его линковщик потом подключает. С какими настройками (инклуда) скомпилирован, с теми и есть.

Comment: а как быть, если заказчик требует разные варианты но код нельзя предоставить? наклепать разных dcu? другие варианты е?

Comment: если у вас 100 разных dcu на выходе получается, то, конечно, сомнительный ход, но других то вроде и нет :)

Comment: понятно. у них в ТЗ просто е пункт "для уменьшения размера приложения в компиляции дожны участвовать только нужные\используемые процедуры". при этом исходный код не берут (но разные варианты компиляции оговорены). как закрыть вопрос правильно - ответить на свой?

Comment: отдать требование про "уменьшения размера приложения" на откуп линковщику с включенной оптимизацией

Comment: @Gu. Экономия на спичках какая-то у заказчика .. если это истинная причина, конечно.

Comment: ну "кризис" типа в стране, экономят.. короче решение понятно.

Comment: как закрыть вопрос правильно - ответить на свой? в принципе решено - или модеры сами закроют? + Kromster спасибо за правку заголовка.

Comment: @teran запостишь ответ? (можно как вики)

Comment: С таким ТЗ там должно быть прописано написание приложения на Delphi 2 с целью уменьшения размера приложения... И, кстати, если в юнит вписать директиву {$RTTI ... [] ...[] ...[]} (см. справку), то вроде линковщик автоматом и будет подключать "только нужные\используемые процедуры". Это можно проверить, скопмилировав в дебаг режиме и посмотрев на неиспользуемые процедуры - рядом с ними не должно быть "точек" для отладки.

Comment: убедили (8символов нужно ля ля тополя) если ответ кто даст, поставлю как ответ. а так что делать? вопрос удалять?